# Show details of an active user after login in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to show the details of the user right after login. here is my code :

---Model---

```
function getDetailsLogin($nama_serv, $no_polisi_serv, $kendaraan_serv, $lokasi_serv, $tgl_serv, $waktu_serv){
        $this ->db-> select('id_service, nama_serv, no_polisi_serv, kendaraan_serv','lokasi_serv','tgl_serv','waktu_serv');
        $this ->db-> from('service');
        $this ->db-> where('nama_serv', $nama_serv);
        $this ->db-> where('no_polisi_serv', $no_polisi_serv);
        $this ->db-> where('kendaraan_serv', $kendaraan_serv);
        $this ->db-> where('lokasi_serv', $lokasi_serv);
        $this ->db-> where('tgl_serv', $tgl_serv);
        $this ->db-> where('waktu_serv', $waktu_serv);
        $query = $this ->db-> get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

---Controller---

```
    public function index(){
        $data['konsumen']=$this->Mymodel->getDetailsLogin(
            'nama_serv', 
            'no_polisi_serv', 
            'kendaraan_serv', 
            'lokasi_serv', 
            'tgl_serv', 
            'waktu_serv'
        );
        $this->load->view('Home/title');
        $this->load->view('Home/navbar');
        $this->load->view('Konsumen/konsumen',$data);
        $this->load->view('Home/footer');
    }
```

---View---

```
  <?php foreach ($konsumen as $key): ?>
    <?php echo $key->nama_serv; ?><br>
    <?php echo $key->no_polisi_serv; ?><br>
    <?php echo $key->kendaraan_serv; ?><br>
  <?php endforeach ?>
```

After i run the code it didn't show anything

EDIT :
So what i want to do is after the users doing registration, users can login, and after login users can see their details informations that they put in the registration form. i already pass the login session, now i want to show user detail informations

and this is my database

Comment: did you debug it? like in mode are you getting any data? Did you do check your query with `$this->db->last_query();die;` before return

Comment: sorry i'm a newbie so i don't really get it. when i add that query check before result, it shows ```SELECT `id_service`, `nama_serv`, `no_polisi_serv`, `kendaraan_serv` FROM `service` WHERE `nama_serv` = 'nama_serv' AND `no_polisi_serv` = 'no_polisi_serv' AND `kendaraan_serv` = 'kendaraan_serv' AND `lokasi_serv` = 'lokasi_serv' AND `tgl_serv` = 'tgl_serv' AND `waktu_serv` = 'waktu_serv'```

Comment: These are (`'nama_serv',  'no_polisi_serv', 'kendaraan_serv',  'lokasi_serv',  'tgl_serv', 'waktu_serv'`) column names. You should send values from controller to model

Comment: ohh okay, then how do i do that?

Comment: why so many where statements? and why do they all reference themselves? e.g. nama_serv = nama_serv ... weird. what is the primary key of the table you use to identify a single user? can you post an image of your database? please try and answer *all* of my questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data['konsumen']=$this->Mymodel->getDetailsLogin(
            'nama_serv', 
            'no_polisi_serv', 
            'kendaraan_serv', 
            'lokasi_serv', 
            'tgl_serv', 
            'waktu_serv'
        );
```

Here in this function don't you need to give values? it looks like you are sending to the function the name of the columns and not the values you want to query by

You could try after

```
    $query = $this ->db-> get();
```

to add

```
$str = $this->db->last_query();
die($str)
```

that will give you the query.

After you the query run in it on directly on the db to see what it returns

Comment: so first, i'm doing registration to input name, password, etc to the database. After that i'm trying to login. I did it, the session is active. now the problem i need to show the details of the active user

Comment: What does $str = $this->db->last_query();
die($str) this return to you ? if you run it with workbench or phpmyadmin does it return any data?

Comment: ```SELECT `id_service`, `nama_serv`, `no_polisi_serv`, `kendaraan_serv` FROM `service` WHERE `nama_serv` = 'nama_serv' AND `no_polisi_serv` = 'no_polisi_serv' AND `kendaraan_serv` = 'kendaraan_serv' AND `lokasi_serv` = 'lokasi_serv' AND `tgl_serv` = 'tgl_serv' AND `waktu_serv` = 'waktu_serv'```

Comment: and if you run that on the db via mysqlworkbench or phpmyadmin or any other db client what does it return?

Comment: then your query is wrong, try changing the where so that the query returns a result

Answer (score 0):

Try using this on your model :

```
function getDetailsLogin($nama_serv, $no_polisi_serv, $kendaraan_serv, $lokasi_serv, $tgl_serv, $waktu_serv){
    $this ->db-> select('id_service, nama_serv, no_polisi_serv, kendaraan_serv','lokasi_serv','tgl_serv','waktu_serv');
    $this->db->from('service');
    $this->db->where('nama_serv', $nama_serv);
    $this->db->where('no_polisi_serv', $no_polisi_serv);
    $this->db->where('kendaraan_serv', $kendaraan_serv);
    $this->db->where('lokasi_serv', $lokasi_serv);
    $this->db->where('tgl_serv', $tgl_serv);
    $this->db->where('waktu_serv', $waktu_serv);
    $query = $this ->db-> get();
    return $query->row();
}
```

If you want to show only 1 (one) person's data, then you don't need a **foreach**.

In your View do this :

```
Nama Service : <?= $key->nama_serv; ?>
Nomor Polisi : <?= $key->no_polisi_serv; ?>
Kendaraan : <?= $key->kendaraan_serv; ?>
```

Salam~

Comment: error in the view. It said Invalid argument supplied for foreach(). maybe there is something i need to change in my controller?

Comment: Delete the foreach, you don't need foreach if you want to show only 1 row of data (1 baris data).

Comment: ^ that, OR he isn't getting any rows which will give the same error because the query is returning num_rows = 0

Comment: when i remove the foreach, the ```$key``` become undefined. Then i'm trying to change it to ```$konsumen``` which is from controller ```$data['konsumen']``` then it says Trying to get property 'nama_serv' of non-object.

Comment: Ohh sorry for that, deleting the foreach you also need to delete the $key. So you can't get the $konsumen data. Are you using "row, row array, result, result array"? Which one do you use? If you use row then use ->, if you use array then use ['the data'];.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your db design is (if this answer doesn't fix the issue please post an image of the schema in your question), but your `where` statements seem useless e.g. `nama_serv = 'nama_serv'`.

I think you want this:

```
function getDetailsLogin(){
        $this->db->select('id_service, nama_serv, no_polisi_serv, kendaraan_serv','lokasi_serv','tgl_serv','waktu_serv');
        $this->db->from('service');
        $this->db->where('primary_key_field', $this->session->userdata('id'));
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
            return $query->row(); // because you just want 1! no foreach required in view.
        }
        return false; // this should never have happened as the user is supposed to be logged in and have a valid session id.
    }
```

where `primary_key_field` is the unique identifier for the current user and `userdata('id')` is the session variable that holds it.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me. I already try your code, still doesn't work, it says too few argument, then i'm trying to delete the arguments then it says Trying to get property 'nama_serv' of non-object

Comment: yes the arguments shouldn't have been there, my bad. did you answer my questions in the comments above?

Comment: i already figure it out, i''ll add the new answer so people can see it, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it. Damn it took me the whole night to figure it out

Since i'm using e-mail for login, then it suppose to be

```
    function getDetailsLogin(){
        $this ->db-> select('*');
        $this->db->from('service');
        $this->db->where('email_serv', $this->session->userdata('email_serv'));
        $query = $this ->db->get()->row();
        return $query;
    }
```

after that, i call it in the view

```
<?php echo $this->Mymodel->getDetailsLogin()->nama_serv; ?>
```

no need the controller

Also Thanks for everyone who trying to help this idiot, really appreciate it :)